# Stopping BackgroundWorker which is searching in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

i wrote a code in c# which takes search criteria from user and search in database table and i done this with the help of background worker 
now while execution if i want to forcefully stop the thread.
because if user gets the result and he dont want the search to be performed anymore

```
btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           backgroundWorkerSearch.CancelAsync();
}

on dowork()
if (backgroundWorkerSearch.CancellationPending)
 {
     e.Cancel = true;
     return;
 }
```

above code doesn't work

Comment: Define "doesn't work"... and at what point does `if (backgroundWorkerSearch.CancellationPending)` execute relative to the rest of the code in the worker? This is *usually* used as part of a loop, for example.

Comment: ' doesn't work ' means though i click on the stop button operation will not be stopped.

Answer (score 4):

Cancellation pending does only tell the DoWork method that the starting thread want's it to abort. It does not automatically stop anything. See this example of a DoWork method:

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
  foreach( ... )
  {
    //do some work
    if( myBackgroundWorker.CancellationPending )
    {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

The other possibility (your case is like this )

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
  //perform a big task towards the database here
}
```

That last case does not give you any entry point to check for cancellation requests, so the ony option is to locate the thread and kill it without giving it the chance to shut down in a good manner, and is not a recommended pattern.

Your best bet is to divide the work inside DoWork in several batches, and check for cancellation requests between each of the sub tasks.